# if div with specific class has an iframe add another class to the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, if div with class .activity-inner contains an iframe I would like to add a class mleft to the div

my code is:

```
$('.activity-inner:has(iframe)').addClass('mleft');
```

but it't not working, mleft class is not added to the div in cases where div with that class has an iframe

I guess there is a simple mistake but I can't find it, I don't have any visible javascript error

thanks

Comment: Looks OK to me. The problem most likely has something to do with the HTML you are using and the timing of when you run the JS.

Comment: Yep, it was a stupid HTML mistake, thank you @Quentin for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Try it with document ready. It is work for me.
Check scripts position on webpage.
https://jsfiddle.net/xted1666/1/

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.activity-inner:has(iframe)').addClass('mleft');
});`

Comment: my problem was in HTML. However my code in the question is not working without document ready so I will give you +1, and it certainly can help someone with the similar problem, thanks